# Create subprocess task in django

Tags: python, django, bash

I have following django models:

```
STATES = (
    ('P', 'PROCESSING'),
    ('F', 'FINISHED'),
    ('W', 'WAITING')
)

class Script(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to='sctipts/') #regular sh sctipt like ./foo

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    output_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    sctipt = models.ForeignKey(Script)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                            choices=STATES,
                            default=WAITING)
```

After a task instance is created, the related bash sctipt should be started. And when it finished, task needs to be updated.
I can't do it in views, because script blocks Django flow.

How to perform this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an asynchronous task queue/job

> Task queues manage background work that must be executed outside the 
>   usual HTTP request-response cycle.
>
> Tasks are handled asynchronously either because they are not initiated
>   by an HTTP request or because they are long-running jobs that would
>   dramatically reduce the performance of an HTTP response.

There are several task queue system that integrate well with Django like **Celery**. I recommend you to read this to understand and choose the right solution : [Full Stack Python - Task queues](http://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html)